# CSS. Поменять пункты списка на галочки

Tags: html, css, список, css-animation

```css
.nameadvantage
{
        font-size: 24px;
        font-family: "OpenSans";
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        text-transform: uppercase;
        line-height: 3;
        position: absolute;
        left: 479.96px;
        top: 1535.996px;
        width: 701px
        height: 238px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="ouradvantage">
        <div class="ouradvantage-info">
            <p class="ouradvantage-titles">наши преимущества</p>
            <div class="nameadvantage">
            <ol>
                <li>Доступные цены</li>
                <li>Оперативное прибытие на место ДТП</li>
                <li>Быстрое и грамотное оформление документов</li>
                <li>Круглосуточная поддержка и обратная связь</li>
            </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Возможно ли вместо пунктов в списке CSS поставить галочки, нарисованные в CSS. Т.е пункты 1, 2, 3, 4 заменить на желтые галочки (как на рисунке), сделанные в СSS?[image: Замена пунктов списка на галочки CSS]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно так

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;    
}


ol{
    list-style: none;
}
ol > li{
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
}
ol > li:before{
    content: '✔';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
  list-style-image: url(//www.gravatar.com/avatar/8b4273496314d7933622f4501dfdaac8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1);
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Доступные цены</li>
  <li>Оперативное прибытие на место ДТП</li>
  <li>Быстрое и грамотное оформление документов</li>
  <li>Круглосуточная поддержка и обратная связь</li>
</ul>
```